# Affine group, identification and multiplication law

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, geometric-invariant

I have a question about the group of affine transformations of $\mathbb{R^2}$.
Where by that I mean the following:
 $Aff(\mathbb{R^2})=\{AX + b\mid  A \in GL_2(\mathbb{R^2}), b \in \mathbb{R^2}\}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ 
c & d 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} p \\ q \end{bmatrix} \right\}$ I think I can identify, topologically this group with the following cartesian product $\mathbb{R^{*4}}\times \mathbb{R^2} \simeq  \mathbb{R^6}$ where $\mathbb{R^{*4}} $ stands for the euclidean four dimensional space without the origin. My question is: is there a simpler topological identification of that group such that I can induce a multiplication law that completely determine the group? In $\mathbb{R^6}$ i found the following product:
$(a,b,c,d,p,q)*(a',b',c',d',p',q')=(aa'+ bc',ab'+bd',a'c+dc',cb'+dd',a'p+b'q+p',c'p+d'q+q')$
The problem specifically is the following: since I need to calculate the left invariant form, I was asking myself if I can define something easier than that. I hope my question was clear enough.

Comment: There are some prolbems I think, one of them: Are u sure that $\mathbb{R}^{*4} \times \mathbb{R}^{2} $ is omeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{6}$?

Comment: Not really, that's why I am asking. I though doing so inspired by $Aff(\mathbb(R))$ can be identified with $\mathbb(R^{*}) \times \mathbb(R)$

Comment: I think the homeomorphism is correct because $Aff(\mathbb{R^2})$ can be written as the semidirect product of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mathbb{R^2}$, and $GL_2 (\mathbb{R})$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^{*4}}$. However I don't think I can find a better structure than that, I though that $\mathbb{R^{*4}}$ can pass to the quotient with the projective space of dimension 3, but I still then miss the part with $\mathbb{R^2}$ and doesn't "simplify" the problem. I think I will calculate the invariant form directly from that composition law through the invariant fields...

Comment: $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{*4}$. You have to remove a quadratic hypersurface from $\mathbb R^4$ corresponding to matrices with vanishing determinant. (For example $mathbb R^{*4}$ is connected whereas $GL(2,\mathbb R)$  has two connected components. If you want to find a nice presentation of $Aff(\mathbb R^2)$ you can realize it within $GL(3,\mathbb R)$.